# Hibernate persistence with Apache Spark causes the process to block

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, transactions, apache-spark

I'm developing long running process that should find RSS feeds that all users in the system have registered to follow, parse these RSS feeds, extract new entries and store it back to the database as Hibernate entities, so user can retrieve it. I want to use Apache Spark to enable parallel processing, since this process might take several hours depending on the number of users.

The approach I thought should work was to use **useridsRDD.foreachPartition**, so I can have separate hibernate session for each partition. I created Database session manager that is initialized for each partition which keeps hibernate session live until the process is over.

Once all RSS feeds from one source are parsed and Feed entities are created, I'm sending the whole list to Database Manager method that saves the whole list in batch:

```
public class DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl implements
   DiggestGeneratorDAO{
    public DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl(){
    setSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession());
 }     
public  <T extends BaseEntity> void saveInBatch(List<T> entities) {
    try{
      boolean isActive = session.getTransaction().isActive();  
        if ( !isActive) {  
            session.beginTransaction();  
        }  
       for(Object entity:entities){
         session.save(entity);
        }           
       session.getTransaction().commit();
     }catch(Exception ex){
    if(session.getTransaction()!=null) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
```

However, this works only if I have one Spark partition. If there are two or more partitions, the whole process is blocked once I try to save the first entity. In order to make the things simpler, I tried to simplify Feed entity, so it doesn't refer and is not referred from any other entity. It also doesn't have any collection.

**UPDATE:**

```
 object DigestManager {
private def createDailyUserSubscribedRSSFeedDigests(date:Date, usersRDD:RDD[Long]){
 usersRDD.foreachPartition {       
   users =>  generateDailySubscribedRSSFeedsDigestForUsersInPartition(users,date)       
 }
}

private def generateDailySubscribedRSSFeedsDigestForUsersInPartition(users:Iterator[Long],date:Date){
val feedsAgregator:FeedsAgregator =new FeedsAgregatorImpl
 users.foreach { userid => feedsAgregator.generateDailySubscribedRSSFeedsDigestForUser(userid, date)}
 }
/**End of DigestManager**/

public class FeedsAgregatorImpl implements FeedsAgregator {


private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FeedsAgregatorImpl.class);
private DiggestGeneratorDAO diggestGeneratorDAO=new DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl();
    private ResourceTokenizer resourceTokenizer=new ResourceTokenizerImpl();

public void generateDailySubscribedRSSFeedsDigestForUser(Long userid, Date dateFrom) {
    User user=null;
    try{
        user=(User) diggestGeneratorDAO.load(User.class, userid);
    }catch(ResourceCouldNotBeLoadedException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String userTokenizedString = resourceTokenizer.getTokenizedStringForUser(user);
    List<FeedSource> subscribedRssSources = diggestGeneratorDAO.getFeedsPreferences(userid).getSubscribedRssSources();

    for (FeedSource feedSource : subscribedRssSources) {
        List<FeedEntry> entries=parseRSSFeed(null, user, feedSource, userTokenizedString);
        if(entries.size()>0){                
            diggestGeneratorDAO.saveInBatch(entries);
        }        
    }

private List<FeedEntry> parseRSSFeed(User blogOwner, User subscribedUser, FeedSource feedSource, String userTokenizedString) {

    String link = feedSource.getLink();
    List<FeedEntry> feedEntries=new ArrayList<FeedEntry>();
    FeedData feedData = feedParser.readFeed(link, feedSource.getLastCheck());
    if (feedData != null && !feedData.getEntries().isEmpty()) {
        for (FeedMessageData feedMessageData : feedData.getEntries()) {

            FeedEntry feedEntry = new FeedEntry();

            feedEntry.setDateCreated(feedMessageData.getPubDate());
            feedEntry.setTitle(feedMessageData.getTitle());
            feedEntry.setDescription(feedMessageData.getDescription());
            feedEntry.setLink(feedMessageData.getLink());
            feedEntry.setImage(feedMessageData.getThumbnail());
            // feedEntry.setFeedSource(feedSource);
            //feedEntry.setMaker(blogOwner);
            // feedEntry.setSubscribedUser(subscribedUser);

            float relevance = (float) 0.0;              
            if (userTokenizedString != null && !userTokenizedString.equals("")) {
                relevance = webPageRelevance.calculateWebPageRelevanceForUser(link, userTokenizedString);
                feedEntry.setRelevance(relevance);
            }
            feedEntries.add(feedEntry);  

    }
    return feedEntries;
}
```

**Update 2:**

I tried to redesign source code and simplified version of it looks something similar like this:

```
usersSparkRDD.forearchPartition{
users=>{
     val genericDao=new genericDAO
     val   session:Session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()
users.foreach{  
             //tried this also
             //val genericDao=new genericDAO
         //val session:Session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()        
         tags=genericDao.loadSomeDataUsingThisSession(session)
         for(tag <- tags){
            val post=createNewEntity(tag)
            genericDao.saveNewEntityUsingTheSameSession(post,session)
             }
             //session.close()
    }
    session.close()     
}
}
}
```

In this approach session is created outside DAO class, and the same session is passed externally to each DAO method. Again, it works if I have only 1 Spark partition, but with more partitions it doesn't work. There are no any thread inside the code where session is created and where session is closed.

**Update 3**

As suggested by [@Vlad Mihelcea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1025118) I investigated thread dumps and found that 2 threads are blocked while trying to save entities. I also excluded Apache-Spark from this, just to be sure there is no problem with it, so I created new Threads which open new session and tries to save entity within it.

```
"Thread-20" #72 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9098030000 nid=0x57a5 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9094c41000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00000000f20c30d0> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-19" #71 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f909802e800 nid=0x57a4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9094d42000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00000000f20c30d0> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-18" #70 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f909802c800 nid=0x57a3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9094e43000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00000000f20c30d0> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-17" #69 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f909802b000 nid=0x57a2 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f9094f44000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.generate(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:147)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000f2b19fd8> (a org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-16" #68 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9098029000 nid=0x57a1 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f9095045000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.generate(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:147)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000f2b19fd8> (a org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-15" #67 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9098027800 nid=0x57a0 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9095145000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00000000f20c30d0> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator$2.getNextValue(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.java:77)
    - locked <0x00000000f2b1a330> (a org.hibernate.id.enhanced.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer)
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.generate(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:218)
    - locked <0x00000000f2b19fd8> (a org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-14" #66 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9098026800 nid=0x579f in Object.wait() [0x00007f9095247000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00000000f20c30d0> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.prosolo.bigdata.twitter.TestJava8Paralelizm$1.run(TestJava8Paralelizm.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Is there anything wrong in my Hibernate configuration?

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        Config config=CommonSettings.getInstance().config;
        String host = config.mysqlConfig.host;
        int port = config.mysqlConfig.port;
        String database = config.mysqlConfig.database;
        String user = config.mysqlConfig.user;
        String password = config.mysqlConfig.password;
        // loads configuration and mappings
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 0);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", update);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size",50);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", 200);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding","UTF-8");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", false);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", true);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", true);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class","org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread" );
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", config.mysqlConfig.jdbcDriver);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://"
                + host + ":" + port + "/" + database+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

        final Reflections reflections = new Reflections("org.prosolo.common.domainmodel");
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
        for (final Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
        }
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
            = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        // builds a session factory from the service registry
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);  

    }

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

**UPDATE 4 (SOLUTION):**

I finally discovered that the problem is in Hibernate data source configuration, and changing to tomcat DataSource solved the issue. In addition to the previous configuration I added the following:

```
 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder
            = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource());
             ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=  serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); 

 /////
 public static DataSource dataSource() {
    MySQLConfig mySQLConfig=CommonSettings.getInstance().config.mysqlConfig;
    String username = mySQLConfig.user;
    String password = mySQLConfig.password;
    String host = mySQLConfig.host;
    int port = mySQLConfig.port;
    String database = mySQLConfig.database;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://"+ host + ":" + port + "/" + database;

    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl(url+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
    p.setDriverClassName(CommonSettings.getInstance().config.mysqlConfig.jdbcDriver);
    p.setUsername(username);
    p.setPassword(password);
    p.setJmxEnabled(false);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    if(CommonSettings.getInstance().config.rabbitMQConfig.distributed){
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(false);
    }else{
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    }
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");
         org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
         ds.setPoolProperties(p);
         return ds;
 }
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a single machine or multiple machines?

Comment: Could you post the complete code for `foreachPartition`?

Comment: Holden, I'm using single machine for development. Didn't try on multiple machines yet.

Comment: I added the complete code for foreachPartition. Dont' be confused, it's mixed Scala/Java project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really taking advantage of [contextual session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session)s here:

```
public DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl(){
    setSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession());
}
```

The session is meant to be bound to a request or to an extended-context but in your use case each DAO instance creates its own session.

If you use two separate DAO instance like `DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl` then they will use a separate Session, a separate transaction and a separate database connection. This can be tricky as chances from one transaction are visible to other transactions only after commit.

The blocking might be caused by a dead-lock between the two concurrent connection/transactions.

You need to refactor the code so that a business method shares the same Session/Transaction/Connection among all DAO calls.

Comment: Hi Vlad. Thank you for your answer. It is actually not session-per-application, but session-per-operation, since DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl instance is created inside foreachPartition as suggested here http://goo.gl/7qxeXQ, so there is a session inside each thread. The approach for using session that I was using is suggested in this article https://goo.gl/dJqtb9. I understand from the article you sent that this is also anti-pattern, but is there any better approach to use entities during the batch process across different sessions without loading it again in each session?

Comment: Why would ResourceTokenizer use the other session? It's not DAO class. I don't use session there at any point. It only access User entity properties, i.e. user.getLearningGoals(), learningGoal.getCompetences()... and get some information out of it, but isn't that supposed to use the same session from the context User entity is loaded from?

Comment: If I try to use getCurrentSession when I initialize DiggestGeneratorDAOImpl, I have org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction. It needs to be opened at this point. I only have one DAO instance per thread, so it's one session in thread (Spark partition), so I still don't understand where the sessions are mixed. My understanding is that each thread must have a separate session, and that should be safe.

Comment: Try setting the 'hibernate.current_session_context_class' Hibernate property to 'thread'.

Comment: This didn't change anything. With this property added to configuration, I still have same exception. Do you think it's relevant to this discussion http://goo.gl/xwUulb ?

Comment: Could you please check my new update? I tried to redesign the code to be sure that sessions are not mixed somewhere, and simplified version of the code looks like in update.

Comment: So, now you know it's not the Session causing the issue. Probably something related to Spark, but I don't know what it can be

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to Spark. I tried to exclude spark and instead to create several java threads that should process in parallel some simple data. Each thread runs new session, and this works fine from JUnit test, but not from my application context. Could it be something related to the fact that I'm running processes as Quartz job and using java.util.Timer (I have exactly the same issue on two different places)?

Comment: It could be that the jobs are somehow blocking each others. If you have a dead-lock, you can spot it by connecting with VisualJVM and check for deadlocks.

Comment: Great idea. I'll check that today.

Comment: You were right. There are some blocked hibernate threads that tries to save entities . I just need to find out how to solve that problem. Any idea what should I do further? I updated my question to include my hibernate configuration. I guess this is now related to thread-safety with hibernate, though, I still don't understand why these threads are blocked since different sessions are used in different threads and examples I tried were very simple.

Comment: Probably you use two synchronized blocks and the order or synchronizing is not preserved.

Comment: You mean that synchronized blocks could be the problem? I didn't use it anywhere in the code. My final code used for testing is very basic. It just opens new session, and saves entity in the same way like given in saveInBatch method in my original post, but only with single entity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It brought me to the solution (see my last update). I accepted and awarded this answer even though it's doesn't contain complete solution, but discussion and proposals in comments brought me to the final solution.

Comment: Great job! I'm glad you found the solution.